# Write html code inside asp.net (C#) (.cs) page

Tags: asp.net, html

I would like to add some paragraphs or new lines or words dynamically but I want to make gaps between every part and the other. How is it possible to do that in the c# code page?

Comment: Please give some more info on your question. Its not clear

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use LiteralControl to add HTML tags like that :

```
Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p>New<br />Line</p>"));
```

Comment: Note that this will just add the control to the page. If you want some control over where the literal will appear you can set the 'runat' property of a div. Then in your code behind use clientDivId.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("html here"));

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it using `lblMessage.Text` and then replacing the `"` character by the `'` character in the HTML code...

```
lblMessage.Text = "<a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Go Back</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you don't want to add markup code to your codebehind pages. But if you must, you can perhaps use HTML's `<p>` element to make different paragraphs. By default, each paragraph has some top and bottom margin to separate it from other elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using **[HttpModule](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307996)**. HttpModule can intercept request and response and modify as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the proper way:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/620b4fzf(VS.71).aspx

So if you like to add what a paragraph with a break inside:

```
HtmlGenericControl paragraph = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
paragraph.Controls.Add(new HtmlGenericControl("br"));
Page.Controls.Add(paragraph );
```